# Find all dependencies that include a given package

Tags: maven, dependencies

I excluded an artifact because it causes conflicts, namely the `jsr311-api` given below. Yet when I run the generated jar I'm still getting the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error. I suspect that another dependency is also including this artifact. How can I find out which one? My dependency list is quite large. Which dependencies include the package `javax.ws.rs.core`?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family; -->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav

and use classname search to find

`javax.ws.rs.core.Response`

If you use a Nexus 2.x in your company, you can use classname search there as well.

If you want to find out where a given *artifact* (that you e.g. found by classnmae search) comes from, use `dependency:tree` in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the mistake was that I had to manually add the javaee api and I set `<scope>provided</scope>` which was a mistake, fixing this solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope><!-- remove this -->
</dependency>
```